# How I get the best combination of offers that gonna limit the vendors(shipping) and I get best possible price using python or machine learning or not

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn

- The user selects from 1 product to {N} products in bucket
- For every product, there are {N} offers from vendors
- And I want to give the user the opportunity to tell him

### My output I want to be:

- IF you take from vendor (A) your total cost for 5 products is 87$
- IF you take from vendor (A) and (B) your total cost for 5 products is 80$ + 
  (x2 shipping cost)
- IF you take from vendor (A)(B) and (C) your total cost for 5 products is 72$ + 
  (x3 shipping cost)

#### python pandas

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(OFFERS)
print(x)


    offer_price  product_id ventor
0           5.0           1      A
1           6.0           1      B
2           7.0           1      C
3           8.0           1      D
4           9.0           1      E
5           5.1           2      A
6           6.1           2      B
7           7.1           2      C
8           8.1           2      D
9           9.1           2      E
10          5.2           3      A
11          6.2           3      B
12          7.2           3      C
13          8.2           3      D
14          9.2           3      E
15         77.2           3      F
16         66.2           3      G
```

> I get a list with JSON format from server

```
OFFERS = [
    {'offer_id': 100, 'product_id': 1, 'vendor':'A', 'offer_price':5.00},
    {'offer_id': 101, 'product_id': 1, 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':6.00},
    {'offer_id': 102, 'product_id': 1, 'vendor':'C', 'offer_price':7.00},
    {'offer_id': 103, 'product_id': 1, 'vendor':'D', 'offer_price':8.00},
    {'offer_id': 104, 'product_id': 1, 'vendor':'E', 'offer_price':9.00},

    {'offer_id': 105, 'product_id': 2, 'vendor':'A', 'offer_price':5.10},
    {'offer_id': 106, 'product_id': 2, 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':6.10},
    {'offer_id': 107, 'product_id': 2, 'vendor':'C', 'offer_price':7.10},
    {'offer_id': 108, 'product_id': 2, 'vendor':'D', 'offer_price':8.10},
    {'offer_id': 109, 'product_id': 2, 'vendor':'E', 'offer_price':9.10},

    {'offer_id': 110, 'product_id': 3, 'vendor':'A', 'offer_price':5.20},
    {'offer_id': 111, 'product_id': 3, 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':6.20},
    {'offer_id': 112, 'product_id': 3, 'vendor':'C', 'offer_price':7.20},
    {'offer_id': 113, 'product_id': 3, 'vendor':'D', 'offer_price':8.20},
    {'offer_id': 114, 'product_id': 3, 'vendor':'E', 'offer_price':9.20}
]
```

### PROBLEM No1

> How I get the best combination of offers that gonna limit the vendors(shipping) and I get best possible price

### My output I want to be:

- IF you take from vendor (A) your total cost for 5 products is 87$
- IF you take from vendor (A) and (B) your total cost for 5 products is 80$ + 
  (x2 shipping cost)
- IF you take from vendor (A)(B) and (C) your total cost for 5 products is 72$ + (x3 shipping cost)

#### My questions are:

- And I think in what is the name of the problem I want to solve?
- Do I need to use machine learning to solve that problem?

> My code so far is with python 3.6
>
> =========================== TRY No1 ============================
>
> #### After 3 hours of digging I come with this but I think this algorithm is very slow
>
> My data have this format:

```
OFFERS = [
    {'offer_id':'oid_1','product_id': 'pid_1', 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':5.00},
    {'offer_id':'oid_1','product_id': 'pid_1', 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':6.00},
    {'offer_id':'oid_2','product_id': 'pid_1', 'vendor':'C', 'offer_price':7.00},
    {'offer_id':'oid_3','product_id': 'pid_1', 'vendor':'D', 'offer_price':2.00},
    {'offer_id':'oid_4','product_id': 'pid_1', 'vendor':'E', 'offer_price':9.00},

    {'offer_id':'oid_5','product_id': 'pid_2', 'vendor':'A', 'offer_price':5.10},
    {'offer_id':'oid_6','product_id': 'pid_2', 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':6.10},
    {'offer_id':'oid_7','product_id': 'pid_2', 'vendor':'C', 'offer_price':7.10},
    {'offer_id':'oid_8','product_id': 'pid_2', 'vendor':'D', 'offer_price':18.10},
    {'offer_id':'oid_9','product_id': 'pid_2', 'vendor':'E', 'offer_price':9.10},

    {'offer_id':'oid_10','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'A', 'offer_price':5.20},
    {'offer_id':'oid_11','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'B', 'offer_price':6.20},
    {'offer_id':'oid_12','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'C', 'offer_price':37.20},
    {'offer_id':'oid_13','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'D', 'offer_price':8.20},
    {'offer_id':'oid_14','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'E', 'offer_price':9.20},
    {'offer_id':'oid_15','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'F', 'offer_price':77.20},
    {'offer_id':'oid_16','product_id': 'pid_3', 'vendor':'G', 'offer_price':66.20},
]
```

#### app.py

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import itertools
import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer



# START MY TIMER TO ESTIMATE HOW LONG TAKE TO CALCULATE
start = timer()
print('Timer Start')

def generate_random_offers():
    ''' Generate random offers with this format:
        {'offer_id':'oid_1','product_id': 'pid_1', 'ventor':'B', 'offer_price':5.00}
    '''

    _offers = []
    _vendors = ['A','B','C','D','E']
    _pids_1 = ['pid_1']
    _pids_2 = ['pid_1','pid_2']
    _pids_3 = ['pid_1','pid_2','pid_3']
    _pids_4 = ['pid_1','pid_2','pid_3','pid_4']
    _pids_5 = ['pid_1','pid_2','pid_3','pid_4','pid_5']
    _pids_6 = ['pid_1','pid_2','pid_3','pid_4','pid_5','pid_6']
    _pids_7 = ['pid_1','pid_2','pid_3','pid_4','pid_5','pid_6','pid_7']

    _pids_5 = ['pid_1','pid_2','pid_3','pid_4','pid_5']
    for i in range(1, 100):
        random_price = round(random.uniform(1, 80), 2)
        random_vendor = random.choice(_vendors)
        random_pid = random.choice(_pids_4)

        print(i)
        schema = {}
        schema['offer_id'] = f'oid_{i}'
        schema['product_id'] = random_pid
        schema['ventor'] = random_vendor
        schema['offer_price'] = random_price
        _offers.append(schema)
    # print(_offers)


    # write_json_file(_offers)
    return _offers
#end

# initiate the variable that gona hold all the offers
OFFERS = []
OFFERS = generate_random_offers()


def get_the_vendors():
    ''' Return array of all individuals vendors in offers array '''

    _vendors = []

    for offer in OFFERS:

        if offer['ventor'] not in _vendors:
            _vendors.append(offer['ventor'])

    # print(vendors)
    return _vendors
#end


def get_the_products():
    ''' Get the products that is inside the array '''

    _products = []

    for offer in OFFERS:

        if offer['product_id'] not in _products:
            _products.append(offer['product_id'])

    # print('products => ', _products)
    return _products
#end


def get_offers_base_on_product():
    ''' Get the offers base on products '''

    _offers_by_product = []
    PRODUCTS = get_the_products()

    for product in PRODUCTS:

        _prod = {}

        p = []
        for offer in OFFERS:

            if offer['product_id'] == product:
                p.append(offer['offer_id'])
                # _prod[offer['product_id']] = p
                _prod = p

        _offers_by_product.append(_prod)

    # print('_offers_by_product', _offers_by_product)
    return _offers_by_product
#end


def get_the_vendors_total_product_price():
    ''' Return the sum of the vendors offers '''

    _v = []
    VENDORS = get_the_vendors()

    for vendor in VENDORS:

        v = []
        _sum = 0

        for offer in OFFERS:

            x = {}
            if offer['ventor'] == vendor:
                _sum += offer['offer_price']
                print('sum of ' + vendor + ' => ',  _sum)

            x['vendor'] = vendor
            x['sum'] = _sum

        _v.append(x)
    print(_v)
    return _v
#end


def compinations():

    list_of_offers_by_product = get_offers_base_on_product()
    a = []
    for _list in list_of_offers_by_product:
        a.append(_list)

    super_compinations = list(itertools.product(*a))
    # print('ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS', super_compinations)
    print(super_compinations[0])
    print(super_compinations[1])
    print(super_compinations[2])

    return super_compinations
#end


def get_sums():

    super_compinations = compinations()
    _sums = []
    best_price = {}
    min_price = 1000
    min_set = ''

    # for i in range(30):
    for i in range(len(super_compinations)):
        price = 0

        for ii in range(len(super_compinations[i])):
            offer_id = super_compinations[i][ii]

            for _offer in OFFERS:

                try:
                    if _offer['offer_id'] == offer_id:
                        price += _offer['offer_price']
                        # print(price)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print('Interrupted')

        _sums.append(price)
        if price < min_price:
            min_price = price
            min_set = super_compinations[i]

    print('========')
    print('OFFERS SUMS => ', _sums)
    print('========')

    print('Min Price: ', min_price)
    print('Min Set: ', min_set)

    # STOP MY TIMER
    elapsed_time = timer() - start # in seconds
    print('TOOK: ', elapsed_time)
#end

# Heare a start the program to calculate all the combinations and 
  after I get all the combinations I try to get the sum of every combination one by one
get_sums() 







 _offers_by_product [['oid_1', 'oid_1', 'oid_2', 'oid_3', 'oid_4'], ['oid_5', 'oid_6', 'oid_7', 'oid_8', 'oid_9'], ['oid_10', 'oid_11', 'oid_12', 'oid_1
3', 'oid_14', 'oid_15', 'oid_16']]


 ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS [
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_10'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_11'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_12'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_13'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_14'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_15'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_5', 'oid_16'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_6', 'oid_10'), 
    ('oid_1', 'oid_6', 'oid_11'), 
    ### N..... Possible combinations mabe 1.000.000 milion
]
```

### this is the output 1Trillion combinations took 20sec

```
[4, 177.64, 206.63, 227.38, 152.29, 202.47, 211.85, 195.35, 171.37, 191.94, 
187.51999999999998, 122.53999999999999, 139.34, 166.43, 135.62, 167.49, 182.12, 169.79
    , 193.42000000000002, 147.42, 176.41, 197.16, 122.07, 172.25, 181.63, 165.13, 141.15, 161.72, 157.3, 150.73999999999998, 167.54, 194.63, 163.82, 195.69, 210.32,
193.54000000000002, 225.41000000000003, 240.04000000000002, 227.71, 251.34000000000003, 205.34,
    234.33, 255.08, 179.99, 230.17000000000002, 239.55, 223.05, 192.67000000000002, 213.24, 208.82]

========
Min Price:  14.08
Min Set:  ('oid_22', 'oid_16', 'oid_9', 'oid_71')
TOOK:  19.05843851931529
PS C:\Users\George35mk\Desktop\MACHINE LERNING EXAMPLES\Hello world>
```

Can someone expert tell me if I am in the right way

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: ok 1min i give you the output

Comment: How many products do you have? 5? And how many vendors? It seems more of a permutation task then machine learning? You can just check the price of all permutation options {AAAAA, AAAAB, AAABA, AAABC .... }

Comment: My code is not give me the best output I want it only makes the sum of the offers by vendor

Comment: The truth is some the customer select (N) Products and for  every product there are (N Offers) the number can be from 0 to 100

Comment: Still then, your current formulation of problem is better off with a permutation approach.

Comment: I update the the question guys

Comment: Vivek yes that I want to do can you show me a small example how to loop and get that combinations

Comment: ```I need to use machine learning to solve that problem``` Why? (don't!)

Comment: I have update the code any Help

Comment: Looks like a knapsack problem to me.

Comment: Thnx Hoefling  I gonna google this right now

Comment: Please write a clear problem with clear examples of input and output (examples list 3 products, text says there are 5).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Machine-Learning, use off-the-shelf solvers for [Mixed-integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (this is a basic [discrete-optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_optimization)) or design your own approximation-algorithms. This problem is probably NP-hard and a lot of popular NP-hard problems share some characteristics and one could learn from them!

Here is some demo which should explain the basic ideas of using Mixed-integer programming for this! There are some caveats though:

- this code is not ready for production (demo!)

  - *bigM* needs tuning; especially for the default-solver (bad; continue reading!)
- this code is using my favorite modelling-tool [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org) (although build for other use-cases)

  - downside: the *default MIP-solver* is as bad as it gets -> only toy-problems!

    - potential remedy:

      - cvxpy supports using some commercial-solvers (Gurobi, CPLEX, Mosek) if available
      - cvxpy also supports good open-source solvers (CBC, GLPK) with a potentially more complex setup needed (Linux recommended; read cvxpy's docs)!

MIP-solvers should be very powerful for this kind of problem. Even in the NP-hard case and difficult instances, one should be able to get a good approximation given some time-limit (and some proven bounds too!)

Alternatively you can try out [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp), which:

- is easy to install (even on windows)
- brings a good default MIP-solver (CBC)
- not as nice (if one likes algebraic-like modelling! but some people like pulp's style and it's install/packaging is top-notch!)

**Good MIP-solvers will be very very hard to beat, even with this simple mathematical-formulation when optimal or good approximations are targeted!**

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import cvxpy as cvx
np.random.seed(1)

""" Synthetic problem """
N = 3  # Products to oder
M = 5 # Vendors

# Shipping costs
v_ship_c = np.random.choice([1, 3, 5], size=M)  # vendor shipping costs if vendor used
                                                # indepenent on number of products

# Product prices
product_prices_mean = np.random.random(size=N) * 50
p_price_v = np.repeat(product_prices_mean, M).reshape(N,M) + np.random.normal(size=(N, M)) * 2
p_price_v = np.clip(p_price_v, 1, np.inf)  # min cost of 1

# Product availability
p_v_avail = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(N, M), p=[0.2, 0.8])

assert np.all(np.count_nonzero(p_v_avail, axis=1) > 0)  # feasible solution

# Print
print('# products ordered: ', N)
print('# vendors: ', M)
print('Vendor shipping costs')
print(v_ship_c)
print('Mean product prices')
print(product_prices_mean)
print('Vendor-specific product prices')
print(p_price_v)
print('Vendor-product availability')
print(p_v_avail)

""" Optimization problem """
bigM = 1e4                                   # big-M constant / CRITICAL!
                                             # "http://scip.zib.de/workshop/scip_lodi.pdf"
X = cvx.Bool(N, M)                           # [p,v] == 1 iff p ordered from v
Y = cvx.Bool(M)                              # [v] == 1 iff vendor v used -> shipping

objective_product_costs = cvx.sum_entries(cvx.mul_elemwise(p_price_v, X))
objective_shipping_costs = sum(v_ship_c * Y)
objective = cvx.Minimize(objective_product_costs + objective_shipping_costs)

constraints = [cvx.sum_entries(X, axis=1) >= 1]  # at least one of each product ordered
                                                # >= more relaxed than == and equal solution
                                                # given costs are positive! 
                                                # will never order 2 as more exp than 1!

not_available = np.where(p_v_avail == 0)
constraints.append(X[not_available] == 0)       # can't order from v if v not having p

constraints.append(cvx.sum_entries(X, axis=0).T <= cvx.mul_elemwise(bigM, Y))  # indicator if vendor used

problem = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
problem.solve()

""" Output solution """
print(problem.status)
print('Total costs: ', problem.value)
print('Product costs: ', round(objective_product_costs.value, 2))
print('Shipping costs: ', round(objective_shipping_costs.value, 2))
print('Order matrix')
print(np.round(X.value))
print('Shipping matrix')
print(np.round(Y.value.T))
```

Output:

```
# products ordered:  3
# vendors:  5
Vendor shipping costs
[3 1 1 3 3]
Mean product prices
[ 7.33779454  4.61692974  9.31301057]
Vendor-specific product prices
[[  5.12592439   4.02876364   2.61085733   9.60848524   5.30376627]
 [  5.89165337   2.89711652   8.162145     2.39620363   4.97935827]
 [ 10.4417003    8.17999011  10.77296176  10.05899815  10.38063239]]
Vendor-product availability
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]]
optimal
Total costs:  18.280935453799668
Product costs:  16.28
Shipping costs:  2.0
Order matrix
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -0.  1.  0.  0.]]
Shipping matrix
[[ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

This small example is solved in 0.01 secs by this toy-solver. Bigger instances will behave different of course!

Comment: Sascha thnx brother for your help , i gonna try this right now :)

Comment: Not sure if i recommend running it. But i recommend research on Mixed-integer-programming in general, MIP-formulations and MIP-solvers. Don't take this code as a final product!

Comment: Ok, i gonna try all that code but if fail no problem I  not gonna give up. I gonna find the solution. But really thank you, Sascha

Comment: I have problem while I try to install the cvxpy

Comment: That's why i recommended taking this approach as a template. Read their docs and you will learn: use anaconda (at least on windows)! Not much fun without.

Comment: Sascha Sorry but I try with cvxpy but I cannot manage to do installed with `pip` I fail all time. but I manage to install the `PULP` .my problem now is ok I know I need to use **MIP-solvers** but is very hard to understand how a MIN-Solver works and be able to use in my problem. Is easy for you to show me an example with `pulp`

Comment: No sorry. That's not what i intend to do. It's about the concept, not about the implementation. The docs of cvxpy explicitly tell you not to use pip. I already mentioned the anaconda-distribution.