# Algorithm to solve stores and products minimum total price

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a JSON array of products with nested array of stores that supply them:

```
let arrayOfProducts =
 [
  {
    "title": "ProductA",
    "stores": [
      {
        "name": "Store1",
        "price": 15.09
      },
      {
        "name": "Store2",
        "price": 16.30,
      },
      {
        "name": "Store4",
        "price": 16.55,
      },
      .
      .
      .
      "title": "ProductB",
      "stores": [
        {
          "name": "Store1",
          "price": 8.06
        },
        {
          "name": "Store3",
          "price": 9.25,
        },
        {
          "name": "Store4",
          "price": 9.27,
          },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
```

I need to find the combination of the minimum number of store(s)(due to extra shipping constraint) that provide all of the products at the lowest TOTAL price.

e.g. lets say the array has five products ProductA-ProductE.There is no single store in their respective arrays that can supply all of them. Store2 supplies a subset of the products and so does any other store.

The output should be like that:

```
[
{
    "name": "store1",
    "price": total_price_for_this_store,
    "products": [ "ProductC"]
},
{
    "name": "store2",
    "price": total_price_for_this_store,
    "products": [ "ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductD"]
},
{
    "name": "store3",
    "price": total_price_for_this_store,
    "products": [ "ProductE"]
}
]
```

I have managed to create the expected output using javascipt's forEach and filter functions, but only to find the solution if one or more stores have ALL the products and not a subset of them.

```
let results = []
arrayOfProducts.forEach((product) => {
  product.stores.forEach(store => {
    let storeIndex = results.findIndex(el => { return el.name === store.name })
    if (storeIndex === -1) { // first occurence of the shop in the array of results
      results.push({
        name: store.name,
        price: store.price,
        products : [product.title]
      })
    } else {
      results[storeIndex].price += store.price
      results[storeIndex].products.push(product.title)
    }
  })
})

let allProducts = results.filter((store) => {
  return store.products.length === arrayOfProducts.length
})

allProducts.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price)
})
```

How can i approach this problem?I dont know how to start.

Does it belong to the LP category of algorithms?

Comment: Please provide the output for this example

Comment: share a code that you have so far and describe where are you stack

Comment: seems like some exam question :)

Comment: it's not an exam question. I am trying to build this for an eshop comparison site.

Comment: A mixed-integer programming approach for the more general problem (including shipping costs): see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46891703/2320035)

Comment: thank's sascha! i ll study your solution.

Comment: That being said: without shipping-costs you should be able to solve this by just iterating over all products and chosing the cheapest store which has that product (trivial and efficient). (but with shipping costs this trivial problem probably becomes NP-hard)

Comment: I updated the question to include  " the minimum number of store(s)(due to extra shipping constraint)". My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a solution:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const _ = require('lodash')

// loading the product JSON file
let product = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('product.json', 'utf8'))

// create a sorted array of the title products
let productTitles = product.map(el => {
  return el.title
}).sort(sortAlphabetically)

let numberOfProducts = productTitles.length

let storeCombinations = []
let stores = []

// create the array of stores
product.forEach((product) => {
  product.stores.forEach(store => {
    let price = store.price
    let productUrl = store.productUrl
    let storeIndex = stores.findIndex(el => { return el.name === store.name })
    if (storeIndex === -1) { // first occurence of the shop in the array of results
      stores.push({
        name: store.name,
        products: [{
          title: product.title,
          price: (parseFloat(price) * product.quantity).toFixed(2)
        }]
      })
    } else {
      stores[storeIndex].products.push({
        title: product.title,
        price: (parseFloat(price) * product.quantity).toFixed(2),
      })
    }
  })
})
let comboCnter = 0

// for each of the stores see if the missing product(s) can be complemented 
// with any of the following stores.
// If true then merge the two store products
stores.forEach((el, index) => {
  for (let i = index + 1; i < stores.length; i++) {
    let currentStoreProducts = el.products.map(product => product.title).sort(sortAlphabetically)
    let nextStoreProducts = stores[i].products.map(product => product.title).sort(sortAlphabetically)

    let mergedArrays = _.uniq(currentStoreProducts.concat(nextStoreProducts))

    if (mergedArrays.length === numberOfProducts) {
      let products1 = []
      let products2 = []

      let store1Price = 0
      let store2Price = 0

      productTitles.forEach(title => {
        let index1 = el.products.findIndex(x => x.title === title)
        let index2 = stores[i].products.findIndex(x => x.title === title)

        if (index1 !== -1 && index2 !== -1) {
          if (parseFloat(el.products[index1].price) < parseFloat(stores[i].products[index2].price)) {
            store1Wins()
          } else {
            store2Wins()
          }
        }

        if (index2 === -1) {
          store1Wins()
        }
        if (index1 === -1) {
          store2Wins()
        }

        function store1Wins() {
          store1Price = (parseFloat(el.products[index1].price) + parseFloat(store1Price)).toFixed(2)
          products1.push({
            title: el.products[index1].title,
            productUrl: el.products[index1].productUrl
          })
        }

        function store2Wins() {
          store2Price = (parseFloat(stores[i].products[index2].price) + parseFloat(store2Price)).toFixed(2)
          products2.push({
            title: stores[i].products[index2].title,
            productUrl: stores[i].products[index2].productUrl
          })
        }

      })

      storeCombinations.push({
        totalPrice: (parseFloat(store1Price) + parseFloat(store2Price)).toFixed(2),
        store1: {
          name: el.name,
          price: store1Price,
          products: products1
        },
        store2: {
          name: stores[i].name,
          price: store2Price,
          products: products2
        }
      })
      comboCnter++
    }
  }
})

// sort the final result ascending prices
storeCombinations.sort((a, b) => {
  return parseFloat(a.totalPrice) - parseFloat(b.totalPrice)
})

fs.writeFileSync('storeCombinations.json', JSON.stringify(storeCombinations))
console.log('comboCnter: ' + comboCnter)



function sortAlphabetically(a, b) {
  let nameA = a.toLowerCase()
  let nameB = b.toLowerCase()
  if (nameA < nameB) { return -1 }// sort string ascending

  if (nameA > nameB) { return 1 }
  return 0 // default return value (no sorting)
}
```

This code finds the cheapest combination of two stores.